# Can't change TextView after Inflate

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I'm trying to edit the text of a textview of an inflated TextView

```
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_1);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.activity_2, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Hello");
```

But, even though textView is not null after inflating, any attempts to change it programatically fail. I can't `setText` on it or influence it at all.

activity_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listviewlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLUTION**

SimpleCursorAdapter inflates the Views itself and so changes were ignored. The view can be accessed from inside the adapter without the need for inflating view by:

```
listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.textView) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText("Hello!");
            # Alternatively get cursor text like so where 2 is the cursor column that has the text:
            # textView.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: please show the xml defination

Comment: Where are you adding the inflated `View` to an on-screen `ViewGroup`?

Comment: @Nativ updated the question with xml

Comment: @MikeM. Is it not possible to grab a View from XML and edit it? I have to add the View to my current screen?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but your code is creating new instances of that `LinearLayout` and `TextView`. If you don't add them to the on-screen `View` hierarchy, you're never gonna see 'em. If you want to modify a `View` that's already there, you don't want to inflate it again. Just get a reference to it with `findViewById()`.

Comment: @MikeM. My main activity and layout has a `listView` which uses the `textView` to create a heading-subheading type list. `SimpleCursorAdapter` handles the `textViews` and then I `setAdapter` on the `listView`

Comment: @MikeM. But I know that the latter isn't the issue because I tried editing the textView before I set the adapter and such and it made no difference

Comment: If I'm understanding you, you're trying to change the text on that `TextView` so that whenever it gets used in your `Adapter`, its text will be "Hello" (as an example). If that's the case, then no, you can't do that. The text needs to be set after the `View` gets inflated, which happens each time the `Adapter` creates a new row for your `ListView`. You'll have to handle that in your `Adapter`.

Comment: Is the inflated layout already a Child from this ViewGroup?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes that's what I'm trying to do. If my Adapter is inflating the View itself, can I not edit the text after it has finished with all of the rows?

Comment: @ViniciusLima I'm not sure of that, how can I check?

Comment: Inflate a view is about data marshalling ( putting your xml into an object, and that's it ). Your changes are getting done, but only inside the object. It is not a member of your ViewGroup hierarchy.

Comment: Try to change your third parameter from inflate to TRUE. From docs: Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Comment: "If my Adapter is inflating the View itself, can I not edit the text after it has finished with all of the rows?" Technically, yes, but you probably don't wanna do that. And inflating the `View` again won't achieve that. You want to modify a `ListView`'s `View`s in the `Adapter`.

Comment: @ViniciusLima Tried changing it to true, same result. The parent of the textView is the second layout.

Comment: @MikeM. You were right, changing it inside the Adapter fixed it. Thanks! Updating question with answer now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your **parent context** like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_2, parent, false);
```